# Suggestion for using Erlang Email archive

Tags: erlang

We work on Email archiving service.The product is written  in Java.Primary functionality is to read the Email- mails from Client's Mail server,MS Exchange in most cases,enrich them with specific parameters and write them to disc. The mails are then archived, indexed and can be searchable.

Mail server we use is Apache James,Apache Lucene for indexing and Jboss as application server for doing other works.So in typical production environment, there will be Load balancer which receives big PST file, then process which reads PST and sends mails to set of Apache James. The middle process does mail archiving on disc and then Lucene for indexing.

We do not face specific  specific concurrency or fault tolerant issues as this entire process is offline, load balancer may recieve the PST file, once in a day.

I was wondering if we can use Erlang in anywhere in the flow ?

Comment: The answer is "yes". You can use it for all, some, or none of a system like that. The real question is what motivates you to desire inclusion of Erlang "just somewhere" if you already have a system that works right now? What need are you trying to satisfy? If you can give a bit more background (organizational, technical, and some explanation of your goals) then someone might be able to give you a more concrete answer.

Comment: As of now there is no specific goal. The various components interact with each other using JMX. Each component exposes their functionality using MXBeans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the details of the index/archive task, the entire stack could be replaced by a smaller Erlang system. By "smaller" I mean it would not involve any external tools and the maintenance and runtime footprint would likely be much smaller, and there would probably be a lot less for developers to remember (specifically, it would get developers out of the operations mindset necessary for webstack-style multi-tool amalgamations). That would do away with James, Lucene and Jboss entirely, but whatever you are using to extract mail from the PSTs would probably remain and push bits over a socket to the Erlang system.

This could be done incrementally, but I think it would be a lot of extra work to get Erlang nodes to work in with a JMX constellation -- that really depends on how well separated from the core logic the JMX bits are. If your current code is written in a way that makes JMX easy to replace, then you could replace those bits with one of the interface libraries that makes Java applications talk with Erlang nodes natively.

It is a big step to get a Java shop to do well with Erlang. So many ways of thinking have to be overturned and a completely alien environment must be learned (Erlang itself is so easy that the language isn't really the issue, its grokking the platform). During the transition it would double the cognitive load on your existing developers. Whether or not that is worth it is purely dependent on your business situation.

While over the very long-term I can't imagine wanting to live in a JVM world for anything that isn't Android, the reality is that most business concerns are not very long-term. I wouldn't want to stick with COBOL, either, but the vast number of businesses that do have sound reasons for doing so.

If your shop regularly engages in refactoring or review of your product then there would be many opportunities to steer things a way that would make this doable without breaking the bank or breaking your team off. If not, I doubt it would be worth it and Erlang would probably be a better fit for an internal project first so your developers can get a feel for things without the pressure of ongoing operations.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer. I am still in phase of learning Erlang.Getting away with JBoss possibly yes, but not sure on Apache Luecene or Apache James. Lucene (cell or node) is used for indexing and searching. Same case for James. Erlang may have SMTP server for sure but not sure advantages of using in this scenario over James.